# Migrate One-to-Many to Many-to-Many relationship (EF Core 6.0)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, blazor, relationship

I'm looking for some guidance on migrating a relationship in my database from One-to-Many to Many-to-Many. I believe this issue is occurring because `Database.EnsureCreated();` was used initially and there are no previous migrations.

When running `Add-Migration RelationshipChange`, the migration attempts to create the tables (but they already exist in the database) and fails. I can comment out the existing table creation lines (all except the join table) but then other tables do not use the join table and it does not work correctly.

Is there a way I can migrate the data to use the join table for a many-to-many relationship in my current situation?

Cheers :)

Comment: You should be using UPDATE, not ADD.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?force_isolation=true&tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do it in two steps. First, make sure your new join table is not part of your DbContext. Then you do an `Add-Migration InitialTables` (or whatever you want to call it) and then delete all the code in the `Up` and `Down` methods where the tables are created. Apply the migration to your database (`Update-Database`). This will get the migration in the database and store the current state where all the tables exist.

Once you've got the initial migration in the database, add your join table to the DbContext and then run your `Add-Migration RelationshipChange`. Now you should get the code to create the join table and all the ALTER statements to add the foreign keys. One more `Update-Database` and you should have everything the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This has partially solved the problem, as the data isn't 'transferred' to the join table and the data gets lost. Is there a way to specify how the previous data/foreign keys should be used in the new table?

Comment: @Anthony Unfortunately, I don't know of an automated way to do this.

Comment: No problem, in the end I modified the RelationshipChange migration and it worked fine :)

Comment: To fix I moved the join-table creation to before old FK is removed. Then right after the join-table is created added a SQL query to select the old FK data and insert into the new join-table.